# Fixed Layout Mobi format did not supporting the points value for letter-spacing and word-spacing styles

Tags: html, css, epub3

I have aligned the Fixed Layout ePub file with word-spacing and letter-spacing styles, but while converting the ePub to mobi, alignments are getting changed.

I have found the reason that, the points value (ex: `**letter-spacing:0.3px; word-spacing: 1.4px;**`) not accepted by Mobi.

How to convert mobi files without changing the text format?  Is there is any alternative styles to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you please check and suggest